# Google OAuthGetRequestToken returns "signature_invalid"

Tags: oauth, google-api, digital-signature, access-token

Trying for hours to get a **request token** using Google OAuthGetRequestToken but it always returns "signature_invalid".

For a test I use the [oAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/) to successfully request the token.  Here are the results:

**Signature base string**

```
  GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgooglecodesamples.com%252Foauth_playground%252Findex.php%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dwww.embeddedanalytics.com%26oauth_nonce%3D56aa884162ed21815a0406725c79cf79%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1321417095%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fanalytics%252Ffeeds%252F
```

**Request/Response**

```
GET /accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Ffeeds%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="56aa884162ed21815a0406725c79cf79", oauth_timestamp="1321417095", oauth_consumer_key="www.embeddedanalytics.com", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fgooglecodesamples.com%2Foauth_playground%2Findex.php", oauth_signature_method="RSA-SHA1", oauth_signature="qRtorIaSFaQdOXW1u6eMQlY9LT2j7ThG5kgkcD6rDcW4MIvzluslFgYRNTuRvnaruraNpItjojtgsrK9deYRKoHBGOlU27SsWy6jECxKczcSECl3cVAcjk7dvbywFMDkgi1ZhTZ5Q%2BFoD60HoVQUYnGUbOO0jPXI48LfkiA5ZN4%3D"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 04:18:15 GMT
Expires: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 04:18:15 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 118
Server: GSE

oauth_token=4%2FmO86qZzixayI2NoUc-hewC--D53R&oauth_token_secret=r0PReF9D83w1d6uP0nyQQm9c&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

I am using Fiddler to trace my calls.  It returns the Signature base string:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgooglecodesamples.com%252Foauth_playground%252Findex.php%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dwww.embeddedanalytics.com%26oauth_nonce%3Dl9Jydzjyzt2fJfM3ltY5yrxxYy2uh1U7%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1321417107%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fanalytics%252Ffeeds%252F
```

Aside from the **oauth_timestamp** and **oauth_nonce** (which should be different), the base string are pretty much identical.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Update 11/20/2011** Thinking it might be something wrong with my RSA-SHA signing, I have since tried HMAC-SHA.  It gives the same results.  I thought it might be beneficial to include the Fiddler results (I added carriage returns to have it format better).

```
GET https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Ffeeds%2F HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_nonce="7C4C900EAACC9C7B62E399A91B81D8DC",
oauth_timestamp="1321845418",
oauth_consumer_key="www.embeddedanalytics.com",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_signature="ows%2BbFTNSR8jVZo53rGBB8%2BfwFM%3D"
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2011 03:16:57 GMT
Expires: Mon, 21 Nov 2011 03:16:57 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 358
Server: GSE

signature_invalid
base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken
&oauth_consumer_key%3Dwww.embeddedanalytics.com
%26oauth_nonce%3D7C4C900EAACC9C7B62E399A91B81D8DC
%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1
%26oauth_timestamp%3D1321845418
%26oauth_version%3D1.0
%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fanalytics%252Ffeeds%252F
```

**Update 11/24/2011** - I want to add more information based on the answers from @Meysam and @Bob Aman.  First, my domain is properly registered with Google.  I have been using **AuthSub** for quite some time now with **Target URL path prefix** set to **http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/authsubsuccess.html**.  Now when I go to the Manage Domains section it states my oAuth consumer key is **www.embeddedanalytics.com**.  Now perhaps this could be a problem.  In the [Registration for Web-Based Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html) document it states:

**If you're using the OAuth interface, this URL (the "Target URL path prefix") must match the value of the oauth_consumer_key parameter**

In my case I have a target URL different from my oauth_consumer_key.  Could this be a problem?  I use **www.embeddedanalytics.com** as the consumer_key in the playground and it works.  I don't want to mess with the target URL because it is currently being used with my AuthSub authorizations.

Comment: @M Schenkel: Though i am using a different library for oauth but getting same issue with Google.Able to get verification code but when trying to get Access Token its giving same error and still clueless whats going wrong.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you use OAuth 2 instead. Much easier to use. No signatures involved.

Comment: Does the playground support OAuth 2?  It appears not; when you do requests from it the header is oauth_version="1.0". If not will there be plans in the future to have it support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googler here. Haven't fielded OAuth 1 questions in a long time because everyone's moving to OAuth 2 (and you should too) but I'll try to go through the usual suspects on invalid signature errors:

- Your server's clock may be wrong. There's a timestamp component and it needs to match ours pretty closely. Try updating your clock against one of the major reference time servers. This happens, but it's an uncommon issue.
- Depending on how low-level the OAuth client you're using is, you may have forgotten to supply part of the key used to generate the signature. The key has two pieces, colon-separated, IIRC. In some parts of the protocol, only one half is needed, but for other parts of the protocol, you need both. I've seen cases where someone kept supplying only the first half when both were needed. Actually, I think I made this mistake myself a couple times.
- Probably not an issue in your case, because you haven't even gotten past the request token, but OAuth 1 requires you to sign the URI query parameters. Failure to do this will cause the signature base strings to mismatch, thus causing the signature to be invalid.
- By far the most common issue is improper encoding. This usually gets expressed as signatures that work sometimes, but fail other times, because sometimes you get lucky and nothing needs to get encoded. I suspect this is what @Meysam ran into based on his comment that he pressed the button a few more times and suddenly it worked.

By the way, if you have to use OAuth 1, you should be using HMAC-SHA1 unless you've got a really good reason to do RSA-SHA1.

Comment: Thanks - I will digest all of this and make more attempts.  I recently did move away from RSA to HMAC.  Regarding the clock, I think it is set properly.  I thought too it could be this and tried changing it an hour here, an hour there.  When I did this it responded "Time too far off".

Comment: Regarding your fourth comment, I too experienced a situation when using the Playgounrd where I had entered in all the information but it responded Invalid Signature.  But clicking the button again I got a valid token.  Does the playground not properly encode??  I also want to add that I have plus (+) signs in my secret key.  This possibly could be a culprit - all other characters are simple numbers/letters.  I added some additional information to the original post.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The playground did have some encoding issues at one point, but I thought they got fixed. Might be a regression.

Comment: Looking into implementing oAuth2 now.

Comment: While this is not the actual technical answer to the question - I realize that moving to oAuth2 is the **real** answer.

Comment: OAuth 2 for this API is a bit tricky because I don't believe it's documented. However, I'm pretty sure if you pick one of our other APIs that support OAuth 2 at random, say the Google+ API, follow the auth instructions for that, and just use the Analytics scope instead, I think that probably works. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Bob, Yes - I am tyring to implement oAuth2 with Federated Login.  I have created yet another Stackoverflow thread with a bounty but have gotten no responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333007/performing-google-federated-login-oauth2-after-initial-authentication

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have not registered your application domain with Google. Therefore, whatever `consumer secret` you are using to sign your request (in HMAC-SHA1 method) will be denied unless you provide `anonymous` as your `oauth_consumer_key` and `consumer secret`. This way, Google will recognize you as an unregistered application and will successfully return you a `Request Token`.

If you use the `HMAC-SHA1` method, the `Consumer Secret` and `Token Secret` will be used to sign your requests. These two secret parameters are known both to your application, and Google, and act like a secret key in a symmetric encryption algorithm.

In order to use `RSA-SHA1` method however, you should have already uploaded your `Public Key` to the server (Google Server) during the registration process of your application. After that, you will use your `Private Key` to sign your OAuth requests. In your case, since you have not registered your application, Google is not aware of your `Public Key`, and therefore using `RSA-SHA1` method to sign your requests with an unknown `Private Key` is of no use.

The first method is usually preferred over the `RSA-SHA1` method for performance reasons. (symmetric encryption is faster than asymmetric one)

So this is the way I could successfully get a `Request Token` in the [OAuth Playground](http://www.googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/):

1. Set 'oauth_consumer_key' to `anonymous` (unless you have
   registered your application and have a real `Consumer Key`)
2. Set 'consumer secret' to `anonymous` (unless you have registered your
   application and have a real `Consumer Secret`)
3. Choose https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/ as the scope of request.
4. Press 'Request token' button

Result:

```
GET /accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Ffeeds%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="116d4df85e784f51cf40f0bc3a967883", oauth_timestamp="1322083727", oauth_consumer_key="anonymous", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.googlecodesamples.com%2Foauth_playground%2Findex.php", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="vVxpbtHlTR%2BJ1yT%2BYS1HOvRzhOs%3D"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:28:47 GMT
Expires: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:28:47 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 118
Server: GSE

oauth_token=4%2F7E_YtZFHuKFPbuAGuCzyj2AsHcha&oauth_token_secret=NHZBJCj2BPxR2HQZhCTwdq2A&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

Now that you have acquired `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, you can press Authorize button. This will redirect you to the login page of Google (if you are not signed in) and then to the page you grant access to the application. By granting access, you will get back to the `callback url` in the playground with a `verifier code`. Pressing 'Access token' button, will get you the `access token`:

```
GET /accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="c222a88cc9f027430b239f4cc6f3f154", oauth_timestamp="1322084080", oauth_consumer_key="anonymous", oauth_verifier="TA6vWcDJC51A9YwMNfmUzmUQ", oauth_token="4%2F7E_YtZFHuKFPbuAGuCzyj2AsHcha", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="q9M%2BjeHNxB2ONPd1DPMn6GriUC8%3D"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:34:40 GMT
Expires: Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:34:40 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 103
Server: GSE

oauth_token=1%2Fxy49iwSQEcqSDbo3cKO-UuPLqvt9qKFit9vaLqR6P-M&oauth_token_secret=IJWB1CVSQfYJJPrf9jXv6SS8
```

*Note: One time, I got the `signature_invalid` response too, even though I had entered anonymous credentials. But after trying again and pressing 'Request token' button one or two more times I made it. I think this should be due to how `nonce` and `timestamp` parameters work to sign the request. This could be the cause of problem. Read [this article](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/16/oauth-timestamps-and-nonces/) for more info.

**Further reading:**

- [Managing the OAuth key and secret](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=162105)
- [Registration for Web-Based Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html)

Comment: @@meysam - thank you very much for all of your efforts.  If there were a way to split points I would have given part of the bounty to you.  Unfortunately the "googler's" answer prompted me to move to oAuth 2.0

Comment: @M Schenkel No problem dude :)